# How can I join two tables but only return rows that don't match specific column which include NULL as well?

Tags: mysql, compare, match

I have two tables which look like this:

```
T1:  ID  |  oldID

T2:  ID  |  newID
```

I basically need to join these tables when their IDs match. However, I only want to return the results like: ID  |  oldID  |  newID where oldID do not equal to newID.

Example data:

`T1: 1  |  100
     2  |  NULL
     3  |  200
     4  |  500`

`T2: 1  |  NULL
     2  |  300
     3  |  200
     4  |  400`

My expected result:

`T3: 1 | 100  | NULL
     2 | NULL | 300
     4 | 500  | 400`

Can anyone point me on the right track?

Comment: select * from T1, T2 where T1.id=T2.id and T1.oldID != T2.newID

Comment: @iamnoten This will not return the NULL value rows.

Comment: if use mysql, select * from T1, T2 where T1.id=T2.id and (T1.oldID != T2.newID or isnull(T1.oldID) or isnull(T2.oldID)).

Comment: sorry, but are you displaying JUST the ID's?  what is the column of 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: @iamnoten if suppose both the oldID and newID is NULL then it will list that also but it should not be listed as both are NULL.

Comment: @Used_By_Already table structure is T1:  ID  |  oldID, T2:  ID  |  newID. You are asking about data, those are rows in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer, Hope this helps

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (ID INT, oldID INT)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES(1,100)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES(2,NULL)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES(3,200)
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES(4,500)

CREATE TABLE #T2 (ID INT, [NewId] INT)
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(1,NULL)
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(2,300)
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(3,200)
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES(4,400)

select T1.ID,T1.oldID,T2.[NewId] 
FROM #T1 T1, #T2 T2 
WHERE T1.id=T2.id and ISNULL(T1.oldID,0) != ISNULL(T2.[NewId],0)

DROP TABLE #T1
DROP TABLE #T2
```

Comment: If it's work means, then why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, didn't have reputation to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server

```
SELECT  T1.ID ,T1.oldID,T2.[newID]
FROM    T1
INNER JOIN T2   ON  T1.ID = T2.ID AND   ISNULL(T1.oldID,0) <> ISNULL(T2.[newID],0)
```

For MySql, use `IFNULL` instead of `ISNULL`.

If zero(`0`) is a value in either `oldID` or `newID`, you can use any other unused values for `ISNULL` function(ie `-1` )

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.ID,t1.oldID,t2.NewId
FROM T1 t1, T2 t2 
WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID 
AND COALESCE(t1.oldID,0) <> COALESCE(t2.NewId,0)
```

### Explanation

```
select t1.ID,t1.oldID,t2.NewId
FROM T1 t1, T2 t2 
WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID #IDs are equal in two tables
AND t1.oldID <> t2.NewId 

Result is:
# ID, oldID, NewId
'4', '500', '400'
```

If you check like this, you will not get the result as you expected, the reason is NULL value not handled properly.
But If you use COALESE means it will check as below:

COALESCE(value1,value2,value3,...)

The above syntax is equivalent to the following IF-THEN-ELSE statement

```
IF value1 is not NULL THEN
 result = value1;
ELSIF value2 is not NULL THEN
 result = value2;
ELSIF value3 is not NULL THEN
 result = value3;
ELSE
 result = NULL;
END IF;
```

Example: 
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 2, 3);  Returns 2

So In our Query,COALESCE(t1.oldID,0) will return 0 if the t1.oldID is null..

```
select t1.ID,t1.oldID,t2.NewId
FROM T1 t1, T2 t2 
WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID 
AND COALESCE(t1.oldID,0) <> COALESCE(t2.NewId,0)
```

Comment: What did COALESCE() func do??

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: COALESCE() function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please add a brief description to the answer (not as a comment) of what you think is causing their problem and how your solution fixes things.